# How to create a dataframe using pandas based on comparing index with values of multiple columns in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data source:

```
raw_data = {'site_394$line_2420$tag_144': {1670231589000: 7,
  1671231589000: 7,
  1672231589000: 9,
  1673231589000: 7},
 'site_395$line_2420$tag_154': {1670231589000: 9,
  1671231589000: 10,
  1672231589000: 25,
  1673231589000: 6}}
```

and

```
events_data=[
    {
      "tag":"site_394$line_2420$tag_144",
      "from_date": 1670231589000,
      "to_date": 1670232589000,
      "event_name": "Event One"
    },
    {
      "tag":"site_394$line_2420$tag_144",
      "from_date": 1671231589000,
      "to_date": 1671332589000,
      "event_name": "Event Two"
    },
    {
        "tag":"site_394$line_2420$tag_144",
      "from_date": 1671231589000,
      "to_date": 1671332589000,
      "event_name": "Event Two Update"
    },
    {
        "tag":"site_394$line_2420$tag_144",
      "from_date": 1670231589100,
      "to_date": 1670232589200,
      "event_name": "Event Three"
    },
     {
         "tag":"site_395$line_2420$tag_154",
      "from_date": 1670231589000,
      "to_date": 1670232589000,
      "event_name": "Event One"
    },
    {
        "tag":"site_395$line_2420$tag_154",
      "from_date": 1671231589000,
      "to_date": 1671332589000,
      "event_name": "Event Two"
    },
    {
      "tag":"site_395$line_2420$tag_154",
      "from_date": 1670231589100,
      "to_date": 1670232589200,
      "event_name": "Event Three"
    }
]
```

I would like to combine the two into a single dataframe as shown below. The logic is, for a column in `raw_data`, if the index of raw data falls between `from_date` and `to_date` in `events_data`, then `event_name` should be replaced in place of value of the respective column. One catch is, if there are multiple matches, then the value should be appended comma separated. If the value of the column in `raw_data` is integer,

Expected result:

|  | site_394$line_2420$tag_144 | site_395$line_2420$tag_154 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1670231589000 | Event One | Event One |
| 1671231589000 | Event Two,Event Two update | Event Two |
| 1672231589000 | 9 | 25.0 |
| 1673231589000 | 7 | 6.0 |

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create dataframe from `raw_data` and than iterate over `events_data` and assign values when the condition is met

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

for event in events_data:
    mask = df.index.to_series().between(event['from_date'], event['to_date'])
    if not (val := df[mask][event['tag']]).empty:
        val = val.iloc[0]
        if type(val) in [int, np.int64]:
            df.loc[mask, event['tag']] = event['event_name']
        else:
            df.loc[mask, event['tag']] = f"{val}, {event['event_name']}"

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                site_394$line_2420$tag_144 site_395$line_2420$tag_154
1670231589000                    Event One                  Event One
1671231589000  Event Two, Event Two Update                  Event Two
1672231589000                            9                         25
1673231589000                            7                          6
```